# Accessing controls from other classes .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I know this has been asked a million times and Ive tried 4-5 different solutions but none of them seem to produce any results.

I have a main form entitled "QoE" and I have two classes entitled "Utils" and and "Tests"

Tests calls a public shared sub from Utils using Utils.ProgressBar()

Utils.ProgressBar() updates a progress bar control from the main form entitled QoE

The ProgressBar modifier option is set to Public but I can't access the control directly from Utils (which I thought I was able to do in the past). Option 2 was to attempt to use this in the Utils class:

```
Dim f1 as New QoE()
f1.ProgressBarMain.Increment(+1)
f1.ProgressPercent.Text = f1.ProgressBarMain.Value.ToString() & "%"
```

but it doesn't produce anything.

option 3-5 was creating a module, a public static class, and trying to put the public shared update sub on the Main form itself. With these options though I usually get the "cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method" error.

So what am I missing? I would love some help. 
Thanks Guys.

---

Edit

---

You're really just splitting hairs here, this is completely valid question even without code, but here is the code non the less:

```
Public Class QoE
End Class

Public Class Utils
    public shared sub ProgressBar
        Dim f1 as New QoE()
        f1.ProgressBarMain.Increment(+1)
        f1.ProgressPercent.Text = f1.ProgressBarMain.Value.ToString() & "%"
        'QoE.ProgressBarMain.Increment(+1) Returns The error mentioned in the comments
    end sub 
End Class

Public Class Tests
    public shared sub DoWork
        Utils.Progressbar()
    End Sub
```

So why cant I access the controls from the QoE form when everything is set to public?
    End Class

Comment: Read very carefully the article for the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).  There is a complete code sample provided there that will achieve exactly what you want to do.

Comment: If "QoE" is the **startup** form as implied by your statement of, "I have a main form entitled "QoE"", then simply use `QoE` to access the controls like this: `QoE.ProgressBarMain.Increment(+1)`, and `QoE.ProgressPercent.Text = QoE.ProgressBarMain.Value.ToString() & "%"`.

Comment: Ive tried QoE.ProgressBar but I always get "reference to a non shared member requires an object reference."

Comment: And there has to be an easier way than using a background worker

Comment: Based on the above, it feels like you might not be understanding how instances of a class differ from one another.  I don't mean this nastily, but it may be worth your while having a look at some "VB Getting Started" tutorials until you understand OOP a little better.  Best of luck.

Comment: What version VB are you working in?  Is QoE the "Startup Object" in Project --> Properties?

Comment: look at my previous posts, I get OOB just fine, I actually have two other projects where calling controls from other forms is working just fine. Just for whatever reason it isnt working here.... Im in vs2010 vb.net fully updated... and yes QoE is the startup object

Comment: Its actually really frustrating, Im currently in one of those other projects and from form2 I can go form1.listbox1.add("this")... and nothing seems different between that project and this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to call controls from other classes you have to initiate the form and all the controls.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Shared f as Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       f = Me
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in other classes just refer to f normally like

```
Form1.f.Textbox1.Text = ""
```

or

```
Form1.f.CheckBox1.Checked = True
```

Enjoy

For some additional reading:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?744677-RESOLVED-Struggling-with-trying-to-access-a-control-on-a-form-from-seperate-classes&p=4563273&highlight=#post4563273

Comment: Not a great solution.  `f` is null in your example.  What happens if you have two Form1s open?

Comment: Why would you have two Form1's? I actually dont think having two Form1's is possible in the same solution. And f wouldnt be null - you are setting f to encompass everything in Form1 (controls, subs, etc.). Give it a try.

Comment: f is nothing until you assign it, something like `f = Me`.  You can make lots of Form1s, too:  `Dim newForm As New Form1`, `newForm.Show()`, etc.

Comment: Notice how your linked reading is not using a Shared variable? Big difference, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to loop through open forms :

```
For Each FORM_ITEM As Form In Application.OpenForms
  If FORM_ITEM.Name = "Form1" Then
    With CType(FORM_ITEM, Form1)

      'Enter your code here

    End with
  End if
Next
```

However, this will apply to every open "Form1". So if you plan to use multiple "Form1", you can set an identifier on Form_Load like Nefariis showed in his answer.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   F = Me
End Sub
```

And use that variable in the loop.